# Automapper, Mapping config isn't persisting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

So the problem.

Ive added

```
AutoMapperConfig.Configure();
```

to the application_Start in global.asax

it runs the code

```
Mapper.Initialize(x =>
{
  x.AddProfile<DomainToViewModelMappingProfile>();
  x.AddProfile<ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile>();
});

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

which runs

```
public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {

        Mapper.CreateMap<DBO.User, ViewModels.UserViewModel>();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<ViewModels.UserViewModel, DBO.User>();
        });
    }
}
```

and everything compiles and runs fine.

but in the controller:

```
UserViewModel model = new UserViewModel();
User user = userService.GetUser(2);
model = Mapper.Map<User, UserViewModel>(user); //this line fails as mapping doesnt exist
return View();
```

but if i add the mapping config in the controller method

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModels.UserViewModel,DBO.User>();
UserViewModel model = new UserViewModel();
User user = userService.GetUser(2);
model = Mapper.Map<User, UserViewModel>(user); //Works great
return View();
```

it works fine.

ignore the different syntax with automapper. Ive tried the deprecated and new way of mapping and both fail.

Thanks

Comment: Why inside `ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile` class you call `CreateMap` inside `Initialize`? I guess that is your problem.

Comment: from what i found online that was the new way of creating mappings as the traditional way has been deprecated. As it turns out that is definitely the problem as the traditional way does work despite what I said in the uestion, my apologies.

Comment: Right, but it looks like you call it twice. And it looks like `ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile` overrides all previous mapping (from `DomainToViewModelMappingProfile`) because it calls `Initialize`

Comment: That makes complete sense. So ignoring what I've read online do you know the way to create mappings not using deprecated methods in the structure I've used?

Comment: I put the described answer. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for that. With you're help I actually worked it out and answered. 1m later you posted your answer but at the core the single line was the thing that needed changing. Which is in your answer too

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're calling `Initialize` method inside your `Profile` which leads to overriding your already existed mappings:

```
public class ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        // you should not to call Initialize method inside your profiles.
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<ViewModels.UserViewModel, DBO.User>();
        });
    }
}
```

And here, you have two ways:

**Way #1** (using the static API - deprecated)

```
public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<DBO.User, ViewModels.UserViewModel>();
    }
}

public class ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModels.UserViewModel, DBO.User>();
    }
}

// initialize your mapper by provided profiles
Mapper.Initialize(x =>
{
  x.AddProfile<DomainToViewModelMappingProfile>();
  x.AddProfile<ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile>();
});

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

**Way #2** (using the instance API)

```
// in this case just call CreateMap from Profile class - its the same as CreateMap on `cfg`
public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public DomainToViewModelMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<DBO.User, ViewModels.UserViewModel>();
    }
}

public class ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ViewModels.UserViewModel, DBO.User>();
    }
}

// initialize you mapper config
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddProfile<DomainToViewModelMappingProfile>();
    cfg.AddProfile<ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile>();
});

// and then use it
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
// or
var mapper = new Mapper(config);
var dest = mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(new Source());
```

In the Way #2 you will need to store you mapper configuration somewhere (static field, DI), and then use it inside your controller. I would like to suggest to inject the `Mapper` instance into your controller (e.g. using some DI container).

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

try to override  "ProfileName" :

```
public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile
{
 public override string ProfileName
    {
        get
        {
            return "DomainToViewModelMappingProfile";
        }
    }

protected override void Configure()
{

    Mapper.CreateMap<DBO.User, ViewModels.UserViewModel>();
}
}
```

Comment: I had tried that as well but as it didn't work I ignored it from the question

Comment: can you share the user entity and the userViewModel ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to  MaKCbIMKo for pointing me in the right direction

As described i dont have to initialize as its already being done in the automapperconfig.

the syntax once in the profile is simply.

```
CreateMap<ViewModels.UserViewModel, DBO.User>();
```

Comment: Please delete this "Answer", add your result to your question or as a comment, and mark @MaKCbIMKo 's answer as the winning answer.

Comment: Ok, wait there. You want me to fix my question with working code that I found. Delete my answer and mark makcblmko as the answer. (No disrespect intended at all to the chap he was incredibly helpful) but it was a full on solution rather than finding what was wrong.